# How to tune Java InputStream size

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp

I am developing file upload functionality in CentOS7 and Jetty9 environment. Everything is working fine but I have noticed that data in my inputstream is very small. I have counted bytes after each read in while loop as bellow.

```
  while ((bytesCount = inStream.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
      ...
      logger.trace("bytecount: " + bytesCount);
      ...
   }
```

Log:

```
 ... bytecount: 3844
 ... bytecount: 4052
 ... bytecount: 44
 ... bytecount: 4052
   .....
   .....
```

My TCP socket buffer size:

```
 cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem
 4096   87380   6291456
```

Is my Jetty9 server reducing the data, so inputstream receiving only around 4KB data each read call? or do I need tune my Linux TCP Socket?

Thanks.

Comment: How is `byteArray` initialized ?

Comment: Is your inputstream buffered?

Comment: Hi @Berger, The byteArray initialized in the following way: byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192]; So, I was expecting my bytesCount should be around 8KB.

Comment: Hi @RealSkeptic, I did not use BufferedInputStream. I have done it by array of bytes instead of BufferedInputStream. I did a try with BufferedInputStream but result is same, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The size of `byteArray` will not determine the minimum read size. Java has underlying streams, so you will get bytes as they come up to a maximum of `byteArray`'s size.

If you want to force it you could tune your Linux TCP socket.

On the other hand, if you do not want to play with you array size in java you can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` with the `toByteArray()` method, which will return an array of the proper size, or google guava's `byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);`